# Management dates on sql server with node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

the code below performs a select on a sql server database, when the code is executed the following error is generated, i have this error: **TypeError: parameter.value.getTime is not a function**

**Input Parameter:**

```
IdUtente=2
dataInizio=01-07-2018 
datafine=02-09-2018
```

**Date:**

01-08-2018

01-10-2018

01-11-2018

02-01-2019

02-08-2018

**JavaScript:**

```
async function CaricaDataeTotaleOre(IdUtente,dataInizio,datafine) {

    console.log("Carica Data e Totale Ore -- IdUtente: "+IdUtente+"\n Data Inizio: "+dataInizio+"\n Data Fine: "+datafine);
    var data = [];
    var query = "SET LANGUAGE 'Italian'  SELECT Distinct CONVERT(varchar(10), DataCreazione, 105) as Data   FROM Marcatura inner join Utente on Utente.IdUtente = Marcatura.IdUtente where Utente.IdUtente = @IdUtente and(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Marcatura.DataCreazione,103) between @Start and @End)  ";
    const ret = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        new sql.ConnectionPool(DbConfig.config).connect().then(pool => {
            return pool.request().input('IdUtente', sql.Int, IdUtente).input('Start', sql.DateTime, dataInizio).input('End', sql.DateTime, datafine).query(query)
        }).then(result => {
            resolve(result);
            sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
            ManageError.SendError("Errore CaricaDataeTotaleOre con : " + IdUtente + "\n Errore: " + err);
            reject(err)
            sql.close();
        });
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < ret.recordset.length; i++) {
        data.push({
            Data: ret.recordset[i].Data
        })
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I think Error is generating from this statement - **return pool.request().input('IdUtente', sql.Int, IdUtente).input('Start', sql.DateTime, dataInizio).input('End', sql.DateTime, datafine).query(query)**.


Try converting the "dataInizio" and "datafine" to new Date object like new Date(String(dataInizio)).

Comment: @DEVCNN with your solution i have this errore:  Validation failed for parameter 'End'. Invalid date.

Comment: check for the value of datafine by console.log() before the return statement.